# Git clone get files by some percentage only

Tags: php, laravel, git

I am trying to clone my GitHub repo to my host in laravel, if my repo is light-weighted it clones just fine, but if my repo is not light-weight is clones by 39% to 44% only and not getting all files.

`Tracks`

```
Checking out files: 24% (125/502)
Checking out files: 25% (126/502)
Checking out files: 26% (131/502)
Checking out files: 27% (136/502)
Checking out files: 28% (141/502)
Checking out files: 29% (146/502)
Checking out files: 30% (151/502)
Checking out files: 31% (156/502)
Checking out files: 32% (161/502) 
Checking out files: 33% (166/502)
Checking out files: 34% (171/502)
Checking out files: 35% (176/502)
Checking out files: 36% (181/502)
Checking out files: 37% (186/502)
Checking out files: 37% (187/502)
Checking out files: 38% (191/502)
Checking out files: 39% (196/502)
Checking out files: 40% (201/502)
Checking out files: 41% (206/502)
Checking out files: 42% (211/502)
Checking out files: 43% (216/502)
Checking out files: 44% (221/502)
```

And it stops!

## Code

```
$command1 = 'cd '.$destination.''; //like: public_html
$command2 = 'git clone '.$repos->repository.' '.$repos->name; //like: https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git

$sshUser = $request->input('serverUser');
$sshPw = $request->input('server_ssh_password');
$ip = $request->input('server_ip');
$port = $request->input('port');
$ssh = new SSH2($ip, $port);
if (!$ssh->login($sshUser, $sshPw)) {
    $sshConnection ='Login Failed';
    Session::flash('danger', 'Login to your server failed, please check your credentials.');
    Log::info('SSH Login Failed '.$sshConnection.'');
    return redirect()->back();
} else {
    $sshConnection = $ssh->exec("$command1 && $command2");
}
```

## Files

`GitHub files`

[image: one]

`files cloned in my host`

[image: two]

**Any idea how to fix that?**

Comment: please verify php time execution time, and disk free space

Comment: @eyetags `max_execution_time = 120` & `free disk "(host) = unlimited` `max_input_time = 120`

Comment: mybe cloning takes more time than 120 secondes, have you tried to pull your repo instead ?

Comment: @eyetags you mean i use `git pull ...`?

Comment: @eyetags when i use `git pull` it returns `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git `

Comment: try to kill any running process and run :  git fsck

Comment: OK, I tried `dd($ssh->exec("git fsck https://github.com/user_name/repo_name.git"));` and it returns `"fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git\n"`

Comment: have you tried that via ssh ?

Comment: @eyetags here are the results `dd($ssh->exec("git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git"));` = `"""
Cloning into 'testapp'...\n
Host key verification failed.\r\n
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n
\n
Please make sure you have the correct access rights\n
and the repository exists.\n
"""` **also** `dd($ssh->exec("git fsck git@github.com:username/reponame.git"));` = `"""
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)\n
error: invalid parameter: expected sha1, got 'git@github.com:username/reponame.git'\n
"""`

Comment: that interesting => Could not read from remote repository.\n \n Please make sure you have the correct access rights\n and the repository exists.

is the repo public /or/ have you properly configure the ssh access ?

Comment: @eyetags yes repo is public, about access, both host and repo belong to myself so i think i should have all accesses right? as you see i get my repo files in my host just not all of them :\

Comment: Have you tried doing a shallow clone for the large repo? `git clone --depth 5 <clone url>`

Comment: @eeijlar what does `--deepth 5` do?

Comment: @eeijlar anyway the result was the same, couldn't get all files in my host